# Hyphen/Dash "-" Symbol's use in Linux bash /dir + GRUB booting

Tags: linux, ubuntu, directory, grub

I am attempting to complete this GitHub tutorial on creating a custom GRUB loader for a stubborn Asus Win8.1 laptop on which I am hoping to install Ubuntu:

https://github.com/lopaka/instructions/blob/master/ubuntu-14.10-install-asus-x205ta.md

(see screenshot image, blue highlighted text)

[image: ../grub-mkimage -d]

Assuming I've followed all of the steps in the tutorial,

**Does this set of commands instruct the machine to create a `../grub-mkimage` directory, 
**or** is it telling the machine to go to the `../grub` directory and create/refer to a `-mkimage` file therein?**

(The full line of bash commands pulled directly from the tutorial I am referring to, just for reference):

```
../grub-mkimage -d . -o bootia32.efi -O i386-efi -p /boot/grub ntfs hfs appleldr boot cat efi_gop efi_uga elf fat hfsplus iso9660 linux keylayouts memdisk minicmd part_apple ext2 extcmd xfs xnu part_bsd part_gpt search search_fs_file chain btrfs loadbios loadenv lvm minix minix2 reiserfs memrw mmap msdospart scsi loopback normal configfile gzio all_video efi_gop efi_uga gfxterm gettext echo boot chain eval
```

Anyway, this is where I've been getting stuck.

**Once I get to this point, the machine takes no further action but to acknowledge that the directory is there:**

```
../grub/grub-mkimage: Is a directory
```

When I attempt to move forward and enter the next command on the tut:

```
cp bootia32.efi /tmp
```

The machine replies:

> cp cannot stat 'bootia32.efi': No such file or directory

It looks like the long command [`../grub-mkimage -d...`] did not install the items necessary to execute these processes.

so, if nothing else...

1. **WHAT DOES the hyphenated portion of `./user/location/folder-HyphenatedNameExtension` actually mean?** It just means it's a file within that folder, right?

and

2. **HOW CAN I re-initiate the `../grub-mkimage -d...` long command again without breaking something?** Would it be wise to restore my system and start over?

Comment: Could you [edit] your question to add the exact error message you get when you try to run `../grub-mkimage`? Also, I removed some of the chit-chat (see the [help tour](http://unix.stackexchange.com/tour)).

Comment: There is no "hyphenated portion": hyphens have no special significance within file or directory names (although there are good reasons to avoid them as initial characters). See [What character sequence should I not allow in a filename?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2304221/what-character-sequence-should-i-not-allow-in-a-filename)

Comment: @EvanExempt: please include the actual *text* of the console or terminal which you gave as a image. Text can be indexed by search engines, you image not.

Answer (score 1):

The sequence of commands you give clones the `grub` repository, changes the current directory to that newly created by `git` (`cd grub`), builds `grub`, changes the directory to `grub-core`, and runs the `grub-mkimage` executable which is in the parent directory.

More explicitly, if you start off in your home directory (I'll imagine it's `/home/evan`):

- `git clone ...` creates a new directory, `/home/evan/grub`, and clones `grub`'s repository in it;
- `cd grub` changes the directory to `/home/evan/grub`;
- the next three commands build `grub`;
- `cd grub-core` changes the directory to `/home/evan/grub/grub-core`;
- `../grub-mkimage ...` attempts to run the `grub-mkimage` command stored in `/home/evan/grub` (the current directory remains `/home/evan/grub/grub-core`).

`..` simply means the parent directory, `../grub-mkimage` means "run the `grub-mkimage` which is in the parent directory". At the point where the command is executed, the current directory is `/home/evan/grub/grub-core`, and the parent directory is `/home/evan/grub`.

I ran the commands you listed above, and the build worked fine for me: `../grub-mkimage ...` created the expected `bootia32.efi` file.

To "re-initiate" the command, I'd say the simplest way for you is to delete the `grub` directory and start over, from the `git clone` onwards.

Comment: Thank you for explaining all of this. I've copied this answer to my reference notes. Wonderful.